# select k values at time and flip them, find minimum cost to make all array values same equal to 1

Tags: algorithm

Given a array containing only 0 and 1 and a integer value k.
You should choose k digits at time and flip all of them. Find **minimum cost** for making all values same. If it is not possible then give **-1**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple greedy problem. I am assuming you can't flip less than `k` digits any time.

> Find minimum cost for making all values same.

To solve this, first we will try to make all values 1 and then we'll try to make all values 0. Between these, which will take minimum steps will be our answer.

Here is my pseudo-code. The pseudo-code is self-explanatory and that's why I am not adding explanation. I am giving code for making all values `1`, hope you can do for both.

```
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length() - k + 1; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == '1') {
            continue;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            arr[i + j] = (arr[i + j] == '0') ? '1' : '0';
        }
        cnt++;
    }

    bool flag = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        if(arr[i] == '0') {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag) {
        print(cnt);
    } else {
        print("-1");
    }
```